# Send Json Data to @Html.Action inside AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am having a div as below,

```
<div id="d1"></div>
```

Its content is to be filled fled with Partial view using an AJAX call.

Below is the AJAX implementation:

```
        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetCustReqChartData", "DA_CPC")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: "{'ProjectID':" + getUrlParameter('PID')"}",
                        success: function (JsonData)
                        {
                            $('#d1').load('@Html.Action("PlotCurrentStatusCountTbl", "DA_CPC", new{ CurrentStatus = JsonData.StatusCount })');
    }
});
```

While i call above AJAX call, i am getting error : 
**The name 'JsonData' does not exist in the current context.**
in the below line :

```
$('#d1').load('@Html.Action("PlotCurrentStatusCountTbl", "DA_CPC", new{ CurrentStatus = JsonData.StatusCount })');
```

How do i pass the javascript variable into `@Html.Action` method.

Comment: The answer is you cannot pass a javascript variable into the `Action` method.  You need to pass the javascript variable to the `load()` function at runtime.

Comment: Using `@Html.Action()` inside a `.load()` makes no sense at all - `Html.Action()` is server side code, and the html that is generated by that is already added to the page when it is first rendered (and of course you cannot use a JavaScript variable in server side code)

Comment: Its impossible to understand what your trying to do here without seeing you controller code, but best guess is that you ajax method should actually calling the `PlotCurrentStatusCountTbl` and then you use `$('#d1').load(....)` to update the DOM with that partial view

Comment: Calling one method to return a your `StatusCount` value and then using that value to then make another ajax call makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Move JsonData out of quotes as the variable response shown below:

```js
$.ajax({            
    success: function (response) {                
        $('#test').append('<li>' + 
            response[i].displayName + '(Not Approved)</li>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**: Razor has no idea what JsonData is.  `JsonData` is not populated and doesn't even exist until run time in the browser.  Razor is interpreted and run by the server when the View is rendered well before and in a completely different context than javascript.

**The Solution**:
There is an overload of [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that takes a data parameter.

```
$('#d1').load('@Html.Action("PlotCurrentStatusCountTbl", "DA_CPC")', {CurrentStatus: JsonData.StatusCount});
```

that way Razor correctly formats the URL and the parameter is determined at runtime by javascript.

Comment: could you please provide the overload method of `jQuery load()`

Comment: @karz linked in the answer now.

Comment: But i need to pass parameter(JsonData) to my `@Html.Action` method. Not `load()` function.

Comment: chat is blocked for me.